# How / Where can I see all TSLint errors for current project in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, tslint

May be I am missing something but I have not found a dedicated place in WebStorm where I can see (and navigate) all errors reported by TSLint.

In the best case I can find the errors while opening a file and pressing F2 (to go to Next Highlighted Error) which not always working as well.

PS. There is a dedicated TypeScript Pane/l in WebStorm but it doesn't show any TSLint errors, neither these reported in Event Log Pane/l.

Comment: You may use `Code | Inspect Code...` .. or a bit "narrowed version" of it: `Code | Run Inspection by Name...` and choose to run TSLint one only. P.S. Yep, this way it needs to be run manually every time (will not auto-refresh if you edit and save your code)

Comment: Thanks for this info, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

1. Select **npm** tab  from the bottom left side.
2. Run linting script (you must have it in package.json).
   See screenshot below for example:
   [List of tslint errors/warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm4ta.png)